# Angular reactive form returning undefined values in service

Tags: angular, angular-services, angular-reactive-forms

I'm trying to get some data from a reactive form and pass it to a service instance. But instead it is returning undefined values  to the service. I've tried to console and get the values in the service but it's returning undefined over there. Please have a look at my code below:

**HTML code for reactive form:**

```
  </div>
  <div class="blog-form" *ngIf="createBlogForm">
    <form [formGroup]="createBlogForm" (ngSubmit)="createBlog()">
      <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label>Blog Title</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogTitle" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter blog Title"
          required>
      </div>
      <div [hidden]="blogTitle.valid || blogTitle.pristine" class="alert alert-danger">
       Blog Title is required 
      </div>

      <div class="form-group form-row">
        <label class="col-md-3">Upload Image</label>
        <div class="col-md-9">
          <input type="file" id="imagePath" (change)="onSelectedFile($event)" />
          <div [innerHTML]="uploadError" class="error"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Description</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogDescription" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Description"
          required>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Enter the blog body</label>
        <textarea formControlName="blogBodyHtml" class="form-control" rows="3" required></textarea>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Author</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="blogAuthor" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Author name"
          required>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Category</label>
        <select formControlName="blogCategory" class="form-control" id="category" required>
              <option *ngFor="let category of possibleCategories" [value]="category">{{category}}</option>
            </select>
      </div>


      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" [disabled]="!createBlogForm.valid">Post the blog</button>

    </form>
  </div>
```

**Angular Component**

```
createBlogForm: FormGroup;
  public imagePath: string;

  public blogTitle: string;
  public blogBodyHtml: string;
  public blogDescription: string;
  public blogCategory: string;
  public blogAuthor: string;
  public possibleCategories = ["Comedy", "Action", "Drama", "Technology","Cooking","Travel"];


  constructor(private blogpostService: BlogpostService, private toastr: ToastrManager, private router: Router, private _http: HttpClient, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
  console.log('CreateBlogComponent component constructor called'); }

  ngOnInit() {
    console.log("CreateBlogComponent onInIt called");

    this.createBlogForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      blogTitle: [''],
      blogDescription: [''],
      blogBodyHtml: [''],
      blogCategory: [''],
      blogAuthor: [''],
      imagePath:['']
    })
}
onSelectedFile(event) {
  const file = event.target.files[0];
  this.createBlogForm.get('imagePath').setValue(file)
  console.log(file)
}
public createBlog(): any {
//console.log(form.value)
  const formData = new FormData();
 //console.log('kk'+this.createBlogForm.get('imagePath').value);
  formData.append('imagePath', this.createBlogForm.get('imagePath').value);
  formData.append('title', this.createBlogForm.get('blogTitle').value);
  formData.append('description', this.createBlogForm.get('blogDescription').value);
  formData.append('blogBody', this.createBlogForm.get('blogBodyHtml').value);
  formData.append('category', this.createBlogForm.get('blogCategory').value);
  formData.append('author', this.createBlogForm.get('blogAuthor').value);

  this.blogpostService.createBlog(formData).subscribe(

    data => {

      this.toastr.successToastr('Blog Posted Susseccfully!', 'Success!');
    },
    error => {
      console.log(error);

    })
}
```

**service file where the formData is passed on consoling the values which it is returning undefined**

```
 public createBlog(formData): Observable<any> {
  console.log(formData.title)   //returning undefined
  const params = new HttpParams()
      .set('title', formData.title)
      .set('description', formData.description)
      .set('blogBody', formData.blogBody)
      .set('category', formData.category)
      .set('author', formData.author)
      .set('imagePath', formData.imagePath)

  let myResponse = this._http.post('http://localhost:4000/api/v1/blogs' + '/create?authToken=' + Cookie.get('authtoken'), params);
  return myResponse;

}
```

Comment: You need to create form controls within the group. ```blogTitle: new FormControl('')```.

Comment: @nullptr.t can you give me an example?

Comment: Are you sure about your `<input type="file" />` ? Don't you need a FileReader() in order to get the good datas ?

Comment: @chatterjeetridib That is an example. Take a look at the [usage notes](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#setvalue) at how the form is being created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `formData.get('title')` instead of `formData.title`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/get